# Access camera inside docker container

Tags: docker

I'm not sure that this is even possible, but is there a way to access my camera inside docker container? I'm not using external camera but built-in in my mac.

Comment: if it is possible, it will require to mount some /dev/xxx like `docker run -v /dev/xxx:/dev/xxx`

Answer (score 25):

I'm not sure that the flag volume (`-v`) is the best practice to do so.

According to the github of jfrazelle, docker engineer who wrote many Dockerfile and `docker run` for many graphical app such as chromium, skype, spotify, and so on, the flag and argument you should use is `--device /dev/video0`.

For quick test(tested on ubuntu), below code should give supported frame resolution of cameras:-

```
docker run --rm -it --entrypoint /bin/bash --device /dev/video0 jrottenberg/ffmpeg
ffmpeg -f video4linux2 -list_formats all -i /dev/video0
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try to forward your webcam device using -v flag

Something like

`sudo docker run -d -p 55555:22 --privileged -v /dev/video0:/dev/video0 testimage`

To list all devices attached to USB use `lsusb` ; to list all devices attached to PCI use `lspci`

Comment: Can I set and running on Docker for Windows system version?

Comment: @NattaWang I think you can't: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37274927/is-it-possible-to-access-a-hardware-device-with-a-docker-image-under-windows?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 1):

On MacOS, it can be a bit tricky:

1. Install legacy docker virtualization engine for Docker Desktop on Mac (which uses Oracle Virtual Box)

   - Install [Virtual Box](https://www.virtualbox.org/)
   - Install [Virtual Box Extension pack](https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/6.1.16/Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack-6.1.16.vbox-extpack)
   - Install [Docker Toolbox](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/docker-toolbox/) (reading [this](https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:YZ8ksEZDEaYJ:https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/docker-toolbox/%20&cd=1&hl=fr&ct=clnk&gl=fr&client=firefox-b-d) is strongly recommended & backuping your `/usr/local/bin/docker*` before is also recommended)

     - Ensure that `/usr/local/bin/docker` and `/usr/local/bin/docker-compose` link to Docker Desktop binaries (`/Applications/Docker.app/Contents/Resources`), and not Docker Toolbox
     - Test everything is still working: `docker ps -a` and `docker images` should display what you already had in Docker Desktop, `docker-machine ls` should not raise an error
2. `brew install socat`
3. `brew install xquartz`
4. Setting: XQuartz Preferences > Security > check allow all (Allow connections from network clients)
5. `defaults write org.macosforge.xquartz.X11 enable_iglx -bool true`
6. `IP=$(ifconfig en0 | grep inet | awk '$1=="inet" {print $2}')`
7. `xhost + $IP`
8. `docker-machine create -d virtualbox --virtualbox-cpu-count=4 --virtualbox-memory=4096 --virtualbox-disk-size=1000000 --virtualbox-boot2docker-url https://github.com/gzupark/boot2docker-webcam-mac/releases/download/18.06.1-ce-usb/boot2docker.iso default`
9. `docker-machine stop default`
10. Open Virtual Box app & configure the VirtualBox VM that has just been created with docker-machine

    1. Display > Video memory (max)
    2. Display > Acceleration > Enable 3D acceleration (check)
    3. Ports > USB > Enable USB controller (check) > USB 2.0 (select)
    4. Shared folders > Add > Folder Path = / & Folder name = host-root
11. Reboot macOS
12. Open a terminal (**T1**), and type

    1. `open -a XQuartz`
    2. If it does not open another terminal, focus XQuartz app, and Applications > Terminal
    3. Now a new terminal is opened (**T2**)
    4. On **T2**: `socat TCP-LISTEN:6000,reuseaddr,fork UNIX-CLIENT:\"$DISPLAY\"`

       - if it complains about "Address already in use", check with `lsof -i tcp:6000` that owning process is X11.bin, otherwise kill owning process and try running socat again (always on **T2**)
13. On **T1** again

    - `IP=$(ifconfig en0 | grep inet | awk '$1=="inet" {print $2}')`
    - `xhost + $IP`
    - `docker-machine start default`
    - `eval $(docker-machine env default)`
    - `vboxmanage list webcams`

      - Identify in the list your webcam (eg mine was `.1`)
    - `vboxmanage controlvm default webcam attach .1`
14. (You may need to open VirtualBox again, double click on your VM, which will open a view of your system, and then Devices > Webcam > <select your camera>)

You should now be able to access your camera in a container.

**Test XQuartz with**

```
docker run --rm -it -e DISPLAY=$IP:0 gns3/xeyes
```

**Test camera with**

```
docker run --rm -it -e DISPLAY=$IP:0 --device=/dev/video0:/dev/video0 -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix ubuntu
apt update && apt install -y streamer
streamer -f jpeg -o image.jpeg
```

**Tip**

Shutdown your greedy VM process with: `VBoxManage controlvm thevm acpipowerbutton`

**Big thanks to:**

- https://github.com/GzuPark/boot2docker-webcam-mac
- https://medium.com/@jijupax/connect-the-webcam-to-docker-on-mac-or-windows-51d894c44468
- https://askubuntu.com/a/106773
- https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/277029

**Additional notes:**

- https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/277029
- https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/docker-toolbox/#docker-toolbox-and-docker-desktop-coexistence
- https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/docker-toolbox/

Comment: waaay too complicated 

Comment: Unfortunately this was the only way I found back in 2020. It may be simpler by now :)